# JQuery button.click not responding

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and HTML and not too sure why my JQuery script here doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated, have a good day!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Game</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#button1').click(function() {
      alert('button clicked');
    });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <body>
    <h1 id="title"><b>GAME</b></h1>
    <div id="button1"><button type="button">Join Game</button></div>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `document` to be ready using [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#button1').click(function() {
           alert('button clicked');
      });
});
```

For the future, always write the scripts at the end of the document so that all the elements are rendered first.

Comment: or do what you just did. I prefer my files at the top in the head